# How to filter by non-null values?

Tags: hasura

Is it possible in the Hasura web app, to filter by values which aren't null?

[image]

Comment: Not possible right now

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about the explorer there, but you can do it easily in the API tabs Graphiql explorer:

```
query {
  my_table(where: {trailer_id: {_is_null: false}}) {
    fields_here
  }
}
```